# If f(x) is normal and convex, how is 1 - f(x)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f(x)$ is convex and normal on an interval $[a,b]$. Can we assume that $1-f(x)$ is ***not normal*** and ***convex***?

Comment: If $f$ and $1-f$ are both convex then $f$ is a *linear* function.

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be "normal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)$ is convex, which implies that $f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})\geq\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}$.

Suppose $g(x)=1-f(x)$. Then

$g(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})-\frac{g(x_1)+g(x_2)}{2}=-f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})+\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}\leq 0$

Hence, if $f(x)$ is a linear function, $g(x)=1-f(x)$ is a linear function.

Otherwise, $g(x)=1-f(x)$ is concave.